# Issues when changing == to ===

Tags: php

What am I missing... when using === in the code, the front end doesn't show an element at all until I disable and then re-enable an option in the WP Customizer.

For example, I have a logo that can be disabled. After installing the theme and viewing the site through the Customizer, the logo shows fine. But when viewing it on the front end, the logo isn't shown at all until I disable the logo and then re-enable again in the Customizer.

Here's the code:

```
<?php if( get_theme_mod('hide_logo') === '') { ?>
LOGO CODE
<?php } ?>
```

== works fine, though I'm making a little theme for sale, and the marketplace requires strict equality checks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`get_theme_mod()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_mod/) could return an explicit `false`. The [`===` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) looks for exact matches, so in the case of `hide_logo` not being set the function would return `false` and false is not an exact match to an empty string `''`.  The `==` operator is a bit more forgiving in that sense which is why you don't have an issue there.

You could supply a default value as the second parameter which will be returned if a value is not set or does not exist:

```
if( '' === get_theme_mod( 'hide_logo', '' ) ) {}
```